# ruby equivalent perl command for replace newlines from file?

Tags: ruby, perl

Im trying to get a equivalent ruby command of this perl command

this is my file

```
centroid
100x50+0+0
28x22+39+9
19x22+68+12
15x23+5+13
15x24+22+10
```

This is my reference perl command:

```
perl -pe 's/\r?\n/,/'  bbb
```

Im using this ruby command but it doesn't work:

```
 ruby -a  -ne   'puts $F[0].gsub(/\r?\n/, ";")' bbb
```

Please help me

Comment: Is it necessary to frame you question in terms of a Perl expression, thereby limiting answers to those familiar with both languages? Can you not simply explain what you want to do?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Come on. Newb did a much better job than most in this case. I don't think we need to get *that* pedantic, do we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `puts` print newline; use `print` which does not print newline.
- Using `$F[0]`, newline is not passed, you don't need to remove newline

---

```
ruby -a -ne 'print $F[0].gsub(/\r?$/, ";")' bbb
```

Comment: I just noticed you're the [only SO user with Ruby and Python golden badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/661694/users-with-golden-ruby-badge-and-silver-python-badge). Congrats!

Answer (score 3):

```
% ruby -p -e 'sub(/\r?\n/, ",")' bbb
centroid,100x50+0+0,28x22+39+9,19x22+68+12,15x23+5+13,15x24+22+10,
```